# New Button not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i've attached this script to a GameObject then to a button script, however the button script  is not showing the 'NewGame' function (click link for image) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuD2v.jpg) . Code seems to have no errors. What could be the problem?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadAndNew : MonoBehaviour {
    public string LoadCode;
    public static string GlobalLoad;
    public string fileName = "SaveGame.dat";

    void Load()

    {

        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.dat"  ))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.dat", FileMode.Open);
            bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

        } 
    }

    void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    void NewGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1); 
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `public` keyword, try this

```
public void NewGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1); 
}
```

You will most likely have the same issue with the `QuitGame` and `Load` functions

Comment: Thanks ! appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For a function to show up in the Button OnClick event slot in the Editor,

- It needs to be made public.
- It must not be a static function.
- It must
  only have one parameter or none.

You are missing the first one I mentioned.

To remove these restrictions, you can instead register the function from code. It will work whether it is a `private` or `public` function.

```
public Button button1;
void Start()
{
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => NewGame());
}

void NewGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

Comment: Certainly a more complete answer